# What do you call it when some group is feeling self-satisfaction by praising themselves?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call it when a group of people is feeling self-satisfied and praising themselves, even though others don't think them praise-worthy?

Comment: It's not an idiom (I like @donothingsuccessfully's answer below), but 'self-congratulatory' can be applied to a group.  It, too, isolates the opinion to the group.

Answer (score 15):

[*Mutual admiration society*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mutual_admiration_society) is apparently an expression in English, used at least as early as 1824.

> A group of two or more people, in a workplace or other social environment, who routinely express considerable esteem and support for one another, sometimes to the point of exaggeration or pretense.

I was about to comment about the Swedish expression *"klubben för inbördes beundran"* that translates to pretty much the same thing, and found the English version while researching it.

Comment: The term was certainly popularised, and probably coined, by [Oliver Wendell Holmes](http://www.oldandsold.com/articles35/american-lit-18.shtml) in the mid 1800s, in reference to the "literary set" of Boston, where he himself was based. It seems he actually quite liked being in that society, and enjoyed giving and receiving praise among peers.

Comment: One might take one of @Jim's suggestions and place it in front of this one if you want to strongly make the point that the Mutual Admiration does not necessarily extend beyond their society.

Answer (score 13):

The potentially offensive phrase "[circle jerk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circle_jerk)" literally means group masturbation, but is used metaphorically to describe this situation.

Comment: This is more appropriate for the OP, given the presumed disapproval of those 'outside' the circle.

Answer (score 6):

I propose that **self-congratulatory** or **self-important** best capture a person who is complacent and self-praising. Words like *smug* or *preening* are more about the manner in which someone expresses conceit.

Answer (score 5):

You could try, *smug, pompous, conceited or vain.*

> smug : highly self-satisfied
>
> pompous: having or exhibiting self-importance
>
> conceited: : having or showing an excessively high opinion of oneself
>
> vain: having or showing undue or excessive pride in one's appearance or achievements

Answer (score 2):

Besides *[smugness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smugness)*, consider *[crowing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crowing), 
[preening](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preening)*, and *[bragging](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bragging)*.  *Brag* means "to boast; to talk with excessive pride about what one has, can do, or has done."

Answer (score 1):

Such people are said to be in an **echo chamber**, in the figurative sense. Or such a group can be called an echo chamber.

***Echo chamber*** -- [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Echo_chamber_(media))

> An echo chamber is a metaphorical description of a situation in which information, ideas, or beliefs are amplified or reinforced by communication and repetition inside a defined system. Inside a figurative echo chamber, official sources often go unquestioned and different or competing views are censored, disallowed, or otherwise underrepresented.

Answer (score 1):

Here, it could be a group, or just one person praising themselves...

> **blow (one's) own horn**
> To boast or brag about one's own abilities, skills, success, achievements, etc.
> [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+one%27s+own+horn)

Answer (score 0):

You could always say that they were / are `gloating`.

[Definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gloating) of 'gloating':

> to observe or think about something with triumphant and often malicious satisfaction, gratification, or delight