# Single word for two people who agree

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for two people (or even better, two judges) who agree on a ruling?

Eg. Her _____ agreed with her on the ruling but disagreed on the reasoning behind the ruling.

Comment: The word "colleague" fits there, but it doesn't have anything to do with agreeing, it just means they work together. I don't think there's a specific word for this.

Comment: Why do you need a word for that, since you specifically say that they agreed. It would be redundant.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find a single word for, say, a judge with a concurring opinion.

Comment: On the strength of the headline alone, I would suggest "kindred spirit." But in the body of the question, it sounds like you're looking for legal jargon. Is that right? Another word unsuited to that context, for example, is "coreligionist." Judges part of the same holding or dissent might be said to "join," but I don't know a noun for such a judge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is it called when like minded people agree with each other praise in a discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347082/what-is-it-called-when-like-minded-people-agree-with-each-other-praise-in-a-disc)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In some contexts you may use **counterpart**.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/counterpart)
> counterpart
> a person or thing that does the same job or has the same function as a person or thing in a different organization, etc:

The case of two judges is especially interesting because it touches on the definition's mention of "*in a different organisation*". It may be argued that two judges are independent and therefore not in the same organisation. But they have the same job and function - to administer justice. As background, see:

> [Courts and Tribunals Judiciary](https://www.judiciary.uk/about-the-judiciary/the-judiciary-the-government-and-the-constitution/jud-acc-ind/independence/#:%7E:text=Independence%20and%20the%20appearance%20of,be%20seen%20to%20be%20done.)
> "It is vital that each judge is able to decide cases solely on the evidence presented in court by the parties and in accordance with the law. Only relevant facts and law should form the basis of a judge’s decision. Only in this way can judges discharge their constitutional responsibility to provide fair and impartial justice; to do justice as Lord Brougham, a 19th Century Lord Chancellor, put it ‘between man and man’ or as Lord Clarke, former Master of the Rolls put it more recently in 2005, ‘between citizen and citizen or between citizen and the state’."

Given this organisational indpendence, one judge may have a counterpart in another and you may safely say "*Her **counterpart** agreed on the ruling but disagreed on the reason.*"

Comment: Thank you all. I think counterpart works best.

Comment: @ElishabenAbbuyah, So, if you think this is the best option, please accept it as the answer!

Comment: @eilia Thank you for that thought. I guess Elishaben is not familiar with the way the site works so has not accepted yet.

Comment: @Anton, You're welcome. This is the only thing we can do in such a situation!

Answer (score -1):

Definitely not a (good) fit for your blank space, but it can describe the situation in a legal context and the term (not a single word) is **[Concurring Decisions](https://www.constitutionalstudies.ca/2020/07/majority-concurring-and-dissenting-decisions/)**.

> In addition to the majority and dissenting decisions, there is a third type of decision a court can deliver called a concurring decision. These decisions result when a judge *agrees* with the ultimate conclusion made by the majority of the court but **disagrees on how they reached that decision**.